# new list for each if

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code:

```
    jobList = self.jobs.findall("JOB")         
    for jitem in jobList:
        self.deployJobs = []
        if jitem.attrib.get("DISABLE") == 'Y':
            self.disablejob = '1'
            self.effectivedate = currentdate
            self.deployJobs.append(jitem.text)
            configXPRandDeploy(self)
            self.deployJobs = []
        elif jitem.attrib.get("EFFECTIVE") == nextdate:
            self.disablejob = '0'
            self.effectivedate = nextdate
            self.deployJobs.append(jitem.text)
            configXPRandDeploy(self)
            self.deployJobs = []
        else:
            self.disablejob = '0'
            self.effectivedate = currentdate
            self.deployJobs.append(jitem.text)
            configXPRandDeploy(self)
```

What I want is for each of the IFs to start with a clear self.deployJobs but I can't seem to figure out the logic.

Comment: I have no clue what you're asking. You already set that variable to an empty list in the beginning of your for loop iterations so they will always be empty lists in the beginning of each if block. You literally can go drink a glass of water, come back, and your problem will be solved.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 then how do I get it to not do the configXPRandDeploy until all the ifs are exhausted?

Comment: Maybe initialize the list before the loop, then clear it at the end of the `else` block?

Comment: @Shashank the problem is it's clearing after each part of the if loop so the list is always 1 entry.  I want the list to contain everything in the if, then when it moves to the elif to be empty again, fill and use that list to run the configXPRandDeploy

Comment: I still don't understand. You should explain more clearly by editing your answer with clear examples. Note that stack overflow code questions are supposed to be in MCVE style: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so basically any irrelevant code that is extra noise is only going to confuse readers.

Comment: @whoisearth you seem to be operating under some severe misconceptions about how for loops work..

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is it's clearing **after each part of the `if` loop**

An `if` statement is not a loop.  The indented code blocks within it (technically, "suites" within it) are not executed sequentially.  Zero or one of those suites will be executed per iteration of the loop, never more than one.

> I want the list to contain everything in the `if`, then **when it moves to the `elif`** to be empty again

Once an `if` or `elif` condition is determined to be true, the suite following *that* `if` or `elif` is executed, and then the entire `if`-`elif`-`else` structure is done.  Execution of the `if` suite will *never* "move to the `elif`".

The [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/) describes the behavior of [`if` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) clearly.

> What I want is for each of the `if`s to start with a clear `self.deployJobs`

Assuming you mean each you want each of the `if` statements *suites* to start with a clear `self.deployJobs`, then you should put your `self.deployJobs = []` line immediately before your `if` statement... which you've already done.

So I'm afraid on this point I have to join the numerous other posters who can't figure out what you want this code to do.  I can suggest, however, that *ending* suites with `self.deployJobs = []` is probably not helping you at all.